# How to get the Image::Magick's blob (raw) image from the Imager?

Tags: image, perl

How to get the same `raw data` from the [Imager](https://metacpan.org/pod/Imager) as from the  [Image::Magick](https://metacpan.org/pod/Image::Magick)'s `ImageToBlob` function for the `GRAY/8bit`?

```
#Image::Magick
my $raw_magic = $im->ImageToBlob(magick => 'GRAY', depth => 8);

#Imager???  the simple 'gray' preset gives different data
my $gray = $img->convert(preset => 'gray');
$gray->write(data => \my $raw_imager, type => 'raw');
```

Probably the `convert` using the `matrix => ...` could help, but can't figure how to use it..

(I need pass the raw data to some another module, which works OK with the `$raw_magic` - so, looking for how to get the same data from the `Imager` .)

If someone want play, here is my test image `qrcode.png` 
[image]
and also my test script.

```
use 5.014;
use warnings;
use Image::Magick;
use Imager;

my $file = shift // 'qrcode.png';
die "missing $file" unless -f $file;

#Image::Magick
my $im = Image::Magick->new;
$im->Read($file);
my $raw_magic = $im->ImageToBlob(magick => 'GRAY', depth => 8);
#hexdump($raw_magic);

#Imager
my $img = Imager->new;
$img->read(file=>$file, type=>'png') or die 'read:', $img->errstr;
my $gray = $img->convert(preset => 'gray');
$gray->write(data => \my $raw_imager, type => 'raw') or die 'write:', $gray->errstr;
#hexdump($raw_imager);

say "Different" if $raw_magic cmp $raw_imager;

sub hexdump {
    my $data = shift;
    my $n;
    print $_, (++$n % 16) ? " " : "\n"
        for unpack '(A2)*', unpack 'H*', $data;
    print "\n";
}
```

### EDIT

Adding some background information. I want to use the [Barcode::ZBar](https://metacpan.org/pod/Barcode::ZBar) package. So, calling my `decode_qr` with the raw data produced by the Image::Magick, the QR-decode decodes correctly the "hello", using the Imager's data doesn't.

```
decode_qr($raw_magic,  $im->Get(qw(columns rows)), 'magick');
decode_qr($raw_imager, $gray->getwidth(), $gray->getheight(), 'imager');

sub decode_qr {
        my($raw, $w, $h, $from) = @_;

        path($from . '.raw')->spew_raw($raw);   #save the raw data

        my $zimage = Barcode::ZBar::Image->new;
        $zimage->set_format('Y800');
        $zimage->set_size( $w, $h );
        $zimage->set_data($raw);
        Barcode::ZBar::ImageScanner->new->scan_image($zimage);
        for my $sym ($zimage->get_symbols) {
                say join(':', $from, $sym->get_type(), $sym->get_data());
        }
}
```

Comment: It looks like `Imager` uses different grayscale weighting coefficients (0.22,0.707,0.071) from `IM`. `IM's` "709RecLuma" looks closer but not identical. Do you need it absolutely accurate?

Comment: The colormatrix looks like the way to go... but I'm only on a mobile at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had a little time to test this out and there is something odd going on. I created a dummy `qrcode.pnm` with ImageMagick:

```
convert -size 1x1! -depth 8 -compress none xc:black xc:white xc:gray xc:gray30 xc:gray90 +append qrcode.pnm
```

And with that, the following code works as expected:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use 5.014;
use warnings;
use Image::Magick;
use Imager;

my $file = shift // 'qrcode.pnm';
die "missing $file" unless -f $file;

#Image::Magick
my $im = Image::Magick->new;
$im->Read($file);
my $raw_magic = $im->ImageToBlob(magick => 'GRAY', depth => 8);
hexdump($raw_magic);

#Imager
my $img = Imager->new;
$img->read(file=>$file,type=>'pnm') or die 'read:', $img->errstr;
my $gray = $img->convert(matrix => [[1,0,0]]);
$gray->write(data => \my $raw_imager, type => 'raw') or die 'write:', $gray->errstr;
hexdump($raw_imager);

say "Different" if $raw_magic cmp $raw_imager;

sub hexdump {
    my $data = shift;
    my $n;
    print $_, (++$n % 16) ? " " : "\n"
        for unpack '(A2)*', unpack 'H*', $data;
    print "\n";
}
```

**Output**

```
00 ff 7e 4d e5
00 ff 7e 4d e5
```

Not sure what that proves, or if it is useful but will spend some more time tomorrow.

Comment: Yes, the numbers looks OK, but the size of the `magick.raw` is only 529 bytes and the `imager.raw` is more the 3174 bytes. I added more information to the question for why a need the conversion.

Comment: Ahhhh.. Finally got the solution. Imager opened the above png image in 16bit/channel. So to get the 8 bit, needed to use `my $img8 = $img->to_rgb8;` and after i used the your `my $gray = $img8->convert(matrix => [[1,0,0]]);` . Accepting, because you helped me.

Comment: @jm666 That's very generous - thank you. But it's fine if you want to put the full, correct solution as an answer for posterity and mark it right for all to see. Good luck with your project.